# Why a variable is set back to initial value in Android Widget, Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I created an `AppWidgetProvider`. It is set as a receiver of the alarms of `AlarmManager`. The alarms are coming, the `onReceived` function is called.

I have a private state variable which is initiated as -1 at the declaration. It is set to 0 in the onEnabled function. It keeps its value in the next `onReceive` function and changes back to the initialized value afterwards.

The results is like this:

```
I/System.out: onEnabled - State: 0
I/System.out: onReceive - state: 0
I/System.out: onReceive - state: -1
I/System.out: onReceive - state: -1
```

When and why the value is reset?
What can I do to keep the value of the state variable between onReceive calls?

```
package com.example.mywidget

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent


class MyWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private val STATE_A : Int = 0
    private val STATE_B : Int = 1
    private val STATE_C : Int = 2

    private var state : Int = -1


    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        println("onReceive - state: $state")
    }


    override fun onDisabled(context: Context?) {
        super.onDisabled(context)
        val alarmManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(context, MyWidget::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, FLAG_MUTABLE)
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
        println("onDisabled ")

    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context?) {
        super.onEnabled(context)
        val alarmManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        var intent = Intent(context, MyWidget::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, FLAG_MUTABLE)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 1000, 10000, pendingIntent)

        state = STATE_A
        println("onEnabled - State: $state")
    }
}
```

Comment: An `AppWidgetProvider` is just a specialized `BroadcastReceiver`. When you register one in the manifest, the system handles creating its instances, and it creates a new one for each broadcast. You cannot maintain state between broadcasts in instance fields. You'll need some other mechanism; e.g., `SharedPreferences`, a database, a file, etc.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer. I changed to Handler-Runnable. It works as I need